# Create a webpage to show the entries send by a form

Tags: java, php, html

Please tell me the codding to create a webpage which can show the information send by another webpage

for eg if a i have created a following webpage

```
<form action="demo.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then I want to know the codding of demo.php so that it can show me my full name which is sent by above codding
Hope you understand what I want to ask......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access those variables like this:

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
```

You can then just echo them out to see them

```
echo 'First Name: ' . $fname . ' | Last Name: ' . $lname;
```

Note that you should be able to see the variables values in the URL of your page since you used the GET method for your form. They will appear like something like

http://yoursite.com/?fname=firstname&lname=lastname

assuming you entered "firstname" as your first name and "lastname" as your last name.

Answer (score 1):

In demo.php add this code

```
   <?php
     $fname = $_GET['fname'];
     $lname = $_GET['lname'];
     echo $fname." ".$lname;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to do that is set Get variables

```
<?php
$fullname = $_GET['Fullname'];
echo $fullname;
?>
```